# Request/Reply explanation

Tags: servicestack

I'm trying to understand how the pattern request/reply has been implemented in ServiceStack/MQServers

assuming the use case from the [wiki](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Rabbit-MQ)

```
mqClient.Publish(new Hello { Name = "World" });

var responseMsg = mqClient.Get<HelloResponse>(QueueNames<HelloResponse>.In);
mqClient.Ack(responseMsg);
responseMsg.GetBody().Result //= Hello, World!
```

Let's say the code snippet has been invoked within a Service Method living in a web application hosted in IIS

```
// web api - IIS hosts the service
public class WebRequestService : Service
{
    public IMessageService MessageService { get; set; }

    public object Any(MyWebRequest request)
    {
        using (var mqClient = MessageService.CreateMessageQueueClient())
        {
            var id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

            mqClient.Publish(new Hello { Id = id });
            var msgCopy = mqClient.Get<HelloResponse>(QueueNames<HelloResponse>.In);

            mqClient.Ack(msgCopy);
            var response = msgCopy.GetBody();
            Logger.DebugFormat("Request for '{0}' replied '{1}'.", id, response.Result);

        }

        return new MyWebRequestResponse
        {
            Result = "result"
        };
    }
}
```

The Publish method send the Hello request to middletier that hosts the HelloService

```
// middletier - winservice hosts the service
public class HelloService : Service
{
    public object Any(Hello req)
    {
        return new HelloResponse
        {
            Result = req.Id
        };
    }
}
```

Since the webapi/WebRequestService receives multiple concurrent requests, how can I achive the "mqClient.Get", after the Publish call, receives the response issued due the related Hello Request? In other word, how can I be sure, in this dummy sample, the Hello.Id(sent through the Publish method) matches with the HelloResponse.Result (received through mqClient.Get)?
How can be ensured the correlation with the published request and its reply?
How can I prevent the mqClient.Get peeks a message not related to the one that has been published in the previous line of code?

The only way I figure out so far is to use the replyTo option so create a queue per each WebApi request, but I don't think that's an option

```
var uid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
string replyToMq = "mq:Hello.replyto." + uid;
mqClient.Publish(new Message<Hello>( new Hello { Id = id })
{
    ReplyTo = replyToMq
});
var msgCopy = mqClient.Get<HelloResponse>(replyToMq);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get a response that's correlated with a specific request you will need to [specify a ReplyTo address](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Rabbit-MQ#responses-from-messages-with-replyto-are-published-to-that-address), e.g:

```
const string replyToMq = mqClient.GetTempQueueName();
mqClient.Publish(new Message<Hello>(new Hello { Name = "World" }) {
    ReplyTo = replyToMq
});

IMessage<HelloResponse> responseMsg = mqClient.Get<HelloResponse>(replyToMq);
mqClient.Ack(responseMsg);
responseMsg.GetBody().Result //= Hello, World!
```

You wouldn't need to specify a `ReplyTo` for long-running (stateless) processes that can generically process any response, i.e. to perform any additional processing after each request has completed.

Comment: mqClient.GetTempQueueName() creates a queue that will be deleted after the message has been peek from that tmp queue  mqClient.Get +  mqClient.Ack. Is that correct? In other word what's happend under the hood is what I proposed as solution plus the auto cleaning of the tmp queue?

Comment: `GetTempQueueName()` declares an **exclusive** and **autoDelete** RabbitMQ Queue which automatically cleans itself when the mqClient connection is closed.